# submit form to string (jquery?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to create a form which submits a string to another page only with the parameter name removed from the URL.

i.e. submitting the following form with "foo"

```
<form action="search.asp" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

will go to `search.asp?foo` NOT `search.asp?keyword=foo`

Can this be done with pure html?
I guess this can be done with javascript and/or jquery but I'm not certain exactly how.

Can anybody help?

I'm a bit of a noob so a copy and paste solution would be great for me.

Update:
Thanks for the answers so far but they don't seem to be working. Perhaps a better way to do this is to get JQuery to construct the URL and load that URL? Any more suggestions would be great.

Comment: are you asking how to send it? or how to receive it? or both? and why would you want to do this?

Comment: The target page can receive it just fine. Unfortunately I'm stuck with some old code (prior to my appointment to this project) and I want to expand the functionality of that page to be accessible through a quick text field from elsewhere throughout the site. I thought it'd be quicker to do it this way than rewrite a lot of old stuff that's linked to other functions and risk breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="search.asp?foo">
```

Answer (score 0):

or maybe...?

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $('form').attr('action', 'search.asp?' + $('input').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's give the form and the submit button a classname for convenience and assume we have jQuery on the page.

```
<form action="search.asp" method="get" class="search_form">
   <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword">
   <input type="submit" value="Go" class="search_button">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var $form = $(".search_form");
    // save the default action, because we are going to mess with it.
    $form.data("original-action", $form.attr("action"));
    // listen to the click on the button, update the form action and submit the form manually
    $(".search_button").click(function(){
      $form.attr("action", $form.data("original-action") + "?" + $("#keyword").val());
      $form.submit();
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Not tested, but should work. Let me know.

Btw, saving the default action is maybe not needed. But just in case that you ever want to submit it with ajax without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        var keywordVal = $("#keyword").val();
        window.location.href = "search.asp?" + keywordVal;          
    });
});
</script>

<input id="keyword" type="text" name="keyword">
<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
```